# Mysql apache2 phpmyadmin on ubuntu

Tags: php, mysql, apache, ubuntu, phpmyadmin

Im working on a school project, im trying to work with apache2, mysql, php, phpmyadmin, on ubuntu 15.04 separately (im NOT using all in one server like wamp or xamp)

Im familiar with working with apache and php, and i need to make a website that uses a sql database, I don't know how to export my project (where I can find my SGBD files?!) and I don't have a clear idea on how to work with phpmyadmin.

I need some tutorials or books that can get me starting with all these technologies.

Comment: Please take a moment to re-read the guidelines for asking questions here in the [Help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The database is exported into `.sql` files from the `phpMyAdmin`, or a command line utility `mysqldump`.

phpMyAdmin Tutorial: http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/installing-and-using-phpmyadmin-for-web-development--cms-21947

And for MySQL try to search YouTube for tutorials. I especially love the tutorials made by Derek Banas, this is his take on MySQL: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yPu6qV5byu4

I hope this helps you become a better developer!

Comment: yep that was very helpful @iSS i think that will give me a nice start. thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to help any time! I strongly recommend Derek Banas for a mentor!